# Help identifying this $25 ebike

Tags: repair, identify-this-bike, electric-bike

I picked up this folding bike for $25 thinking I would google it and have all the info I needed to get it functioning.
Any help finding documentation would be great, what kind of battery can I plug into it would be great start.
Thank you
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is it, but: https://youtu.be/PsiKbHrHBbQ

Comment: It's obviously missing batteries.  Is there any lettering on the battery case telling you what batteries are used?

Comment: From the size of the compartment and the apparent age of the bike I would guess that the batteries are either nicad or lead-acid.

Comment: The screwy thing on the side of the battery compartment is probably the charging port.

Comment: I'm guessing it takes two batteries.  Something like a Batteries Plus in your area may be able to guess at the type.

Comment: Looks like a fairly standard 6V lead acid battery container and fly leads to me, the round port and chain cover is possible an auxiliary power out but it looks very burnt out, possibly the cause of the removed battery.